# How to pause on a content within a page?

Tags: jquery, css

I want a certain page to stop on a particular content once the scroll hits that part. It will only proceed scrolling once a certain condition is met (i.e. sketch something, click something within that div, etc.)

How do you make this happen? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the default scrolling action by binding a handler on document scroll, and calling e.preventDefault().

Here, contentPos is the y position in pixels where you want to stop scrolling, this is compared with $(document).scrollTop().

```
$(document).
    bind( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function ( e ) {

        contentYPos = 500;
        conditionMet = false;

        if ($(document).scrollTop() >= contentYPos
            && conditionMet == false 
            && e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {

               e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

This will check if your conditionMet is false, and if the user is scrolling down (presumably you want the window to still be able to scroll up), it will override that action until the condition is met.

Here is a js fiddle showing this working: http://jsfiddle.net/cMKh2/

Edit: Included a more comprehensive version which fires on window scroll. (Both methods included for comparison).

http://jsfiddle.net/cMKh2/2/

Edit2: Final version with condition changed via button press, and dynamic scroll distance.

http://jsfiddle.net/cMKh2/4/

Comment: This is in an assumption that you know the length until it reaches to where it should stop. My plan was to implement this on an article then once it sees the container via scroll, it stops there. Also, how does this work when there's an else statement so it could proceed once the conditions are met?

Comment: Replace contentYPos with $("#element").offset().top, and it will stop dynamically.

Here is a fiddle showing what you want. It will stop scrolling at the blue element until the button is clicked, which changes the conditionMet variable to true. This prevents the scroll from locking. Hopefully this should be what you want!

http://jsfiddle.net/cMKh2/4/

Comment: Hmm... This is close to what I want. But one more thing, is it possible to count the scrolling before it proceeds? I plan to detect a scroll event as opposed to a click event.

Comment: I tried implementing your code on my own markup. This does not seem to work. Look in here: http://jsfiddle.net/ralphcarlo/8xCtJ/1/

Just a heads up, I am using Foundation framework, hence with the huge blocks of css code.