# Is there a way to determine how many scrolls have been made on a window?

Tags: jquery, scroll

In relation to this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374319/how-to-pause-on-a-content-within-a-page)**.

Is there a way to determine the number of scrolls made before executing an action on jQuery? Currently, what I want to happen is instead of a click event, the scroll event will trigger on the nth number of scroll (say, third scroll event). Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you meant..

```
var i = 0;

$( window ).scroll(function() {
  i++;
  alert(i);
  if(i == 3){
        //Your code
  }
```

});

Comment: Could you look into this? This is basically the whole idea. Right now, it works when button is clicked. **[See this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374319/how-to-pause-on-a-content-within-a-page)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var scrolled = 0, can_count = true;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if (!can_count) return false;
    can_count = false;
    scrolled++;
    // if (scrolled == 3) {...}
    setTimeout(function(){ can_count = true; }, 800);
});
```

note that scroll event is fired on EVERY scroll, meaning- on a 'single' scroll performed by a mouse or trackpad, you'll probably fire MULTIPLE scroll events, which i'm not sure is good in your case.

iv'e added a timer that will allow 1 scroll event each 800 miliseconds, which should be more accurate to your need.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var count = 0;
var prev_scroll = 0;
var success = 1;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(count >= 50){
        alert("you did 50 down scrolls");
        count = 0;
        success = 0;
    }
    if(success == 1 && $(window).scrollTop() > 500)
    {
        $(window).scrollTop(500);
        count++;
    }
    if(success == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() == 0)
    {
        /*reset success*/
        success = 1;
    }
    prev_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3kPaB/11/

This will prevent the user from going below 500px scroll without scrolling 50 times.
You can combine this with the 800 millisecond timeout provided by Gal V since 50 times is reached very easily.

Comment: Can this be applicable on mobile scroll?

Comment: Not pretty, but it would.

Answer (score 0):

I forked the jsfiddle in the linked post

http://jsfiddle.net/Mw9B6/8/

```
if(count > 50){
    conditionMet = true;
}
```

Condition is met when scrolling 50 times or by clicking the button, and as said before, the 800 millisecond timeout could/should be used.

That should answer your question.